# Revoke access to kubernetes cluster on google container engine

Tags: security, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm hosting on google container engine. Recently one of my team mates left the company and I want to revoke his access rights to the cluster. I removed his account from the compute engine project already, yet he can still access the cluster.

He got access through `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster>`. The entries I see in my `~/.kube/config` look as if I get the same certificate as all of my colleagues.

What do I need to do to remove him from the cluster? To me it seems as if there is zero documentation on this topic.

*Additional Note:*
The cluster is still on kubernetes 1.2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the per-cluster certificate, there is currently no way to revoke/rotate certificates (see [Issue #4672](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4672)). The only way to completely revoke access is to delete and recreate the cluster.

If you instead use Google OAuth2 credentials to access your cluster (the default w/ a 1.3 cluster and an up-to-date client), permissions are tied to your project's [IAM configuration](http://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project), and can be revoked/changed at any time.

Retrieving the cluster certificate requires the caller to have `container.clusters.getCredentials` permission, which is contained by the `Container Engine Admin` and `Editor` roles. As long as the roles that you give to your team members do not contain that permission (e.g. `Container Engine Developer`), they will not be able to retrieve cluster certificates.

Here are the [GKE IAM docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/iam-integration) for more info on GKE permissions and roles.

Comment: Thanks! Now that is reason to upgrade the cluster.

Comment: How can we verify that we're actually using OAuth2 credentials to access the cluster? Is it possible to block anyone from using the per-cluster certificate?

Comment: Look at the output of `kubectl config view`. There should be a `user` corresponding to each cluster. If the `user` has an `auth-provider` w/ `name: gcp`, you are using OAuth2 credentials. If the user has `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` or `username` and `password`, you are using per-cluster credentials.